# MongoDB: GeoJSON object type index, Can't extract geo keys

Tags: mongodb

I have made many the below GeoJSON Point objects in MongoDB Compass as per the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e86d275a3d7fd05e4f022a8"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "point",
        "coordinates": ["-110.85458435", "39.68476146"]
    },
    "website": "carbonmedicalservice.com",
    "address": "125 S Main St",
    "state": "UT",
    "zip": "84526",
    "name": "Carbon Medical"
}
```

I want to be able te search the collection to return all records within an reactangle, I believe I need to add a Geospatial Indexe to the location but I get the error shown below...

[image]

This is how I entered the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a GeoJSON type, coordinates should be float/double not string.

Also, the type should be `Point`, not `point` in your case. So, the GeoJSON in your case should be:

```
{
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [-110.85458435, 39.68476146]
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "type": "point",
  "coordinates": ["-110.85458435", "39.68476146"]
}
```

Comment: When you say coordinates should be `numeric` what is the exact type int32 or int 64 or double?

Comment: Edited, I meant float/double not string.

Comment: perfect, thank you, I have now created a geospatial index